# PHP + Slim での、インスタンスメソッド呼び出しの際に使われる 「: (コロン記号)」に関して

Tags: php, slim, url-routing

PHP　での、コロンの意味について教えて下さい。

最近　PHP　を学習しだした者です。

書籍にて、　Slim　フレームワークのサンプルがあったので、それを意味を理解しながら、写経しています。
そこで不明な点が有りましたので、質問します。

↓ Slimサンプルアプリケーション [Tinitter のコード](https://github.com/uzulla/Tinitter/blob/master/lib/Tinitter/Route.php#L14)で、

```
$app->get('/', '\Tinitter\Controller\TimeLine:show');
```

とあります。

`TimeLine:show` のコロンはなぜ一つなのでしょうか??

`TimeLine` クラスのクラスメソッドの `show` を呼んでいるのですが、 `TimeLine::show` ではないのでしょうか??

インスタンスメソッドの時は、アロー演算子で呼び出すと思うのですが、クラスメソッドの時は、 `::` ではなくて、 `:` を間に挟んで呼び出すということなのでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

これは、 Slim 独自の表現で、 PHP とは関係がありません。

件は、URL による、処理のルーティング（振り分け）の部分です。URLのパターンを決め、パターンにマッチしたものをどうするか指定しています。

```
$app->get('/', '\Tinitter\Controller\TimeLine:show');
```

→ 「 `/` に HTTP アクセスがあったならば、 `TimeLine` をインスタンス化して、 `show` メソッドを HTTPを処理するメソッドとして使用する」という指定だと考えられます。<s>アクセスごとに丁寧にインスタンス化するあたり、PHP 的ですね。</s>

`:` でインスタンスメソッド指定する方法は、 Slim 2.4.0 に追加されたものらしく、[ドキュメント](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Parameters)に載っていなさそうですので、疑問を持たれたのは当然かと思います。[リリースノートには他に](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/releases/tag/2.4.0)、　`::` の指定で、スタティックメソッド呼び出しになるらしいことが言及されています。

参考: [Slim Framework Document: Route Parameters](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Parameters)

Comment: 質問の修正と、ご回答ありがとうございました。
質問していた内容に加えて、ルーティングに関してもよく理解出来ました。

Answer (score 0):

```
$app->get('/', '\Tinitter\Controller\TimeLine:show');
```

このコードにおける `'\Tinitter\Controller\TimeLine:show'` の部分は、PHPの言語構造としては単なる「文字列」です。クラスとメソッドに対応するものが書かれているので、PHPの言語構造のように見えてしまって紛らわしいですが、この文字列からPHPが何か解釈をするわけではありません。

Slimフレームワークのコードで上記のように `$app->get()` を呼び出した時、フレームワーク内の[`Route`クラスの`setCallable()`メソッド](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/blob/master/Slim/Route.php#L162)が呼ばれます。

```
public function setCallable($callable)
{
    $matches = array();
    if (is_string($callable) && preg_match('!^([^\:]+)\:([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)$!', $callable, $matches)) {
        $class = $matches[1];
        $method = $matches[2];
        $callable = function() use ($class, $method) {
            static $obj = null;
            if ($obj === null) {
                $obj = new $class;
            }
            return call_user_func_array(array($obj, $method), func_get_args());
        };
    }
    if (!is_callable($callable)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Route callable must be callable');
    }
    $this->callable = $callable;
}
```

このコードを見ると、指定されたものが文字列で、かつコロンがある場合に、それをクラス名とメソッドに分割してから、クラスをインスタンス化していることがわかります。

Comment: 回答有難うございました。なるほど、確かに、php上では文字列ですね。
引用してくださったフレームワークのコードを見ると、クラス名とメソッドに分割していることが理解出来ました。今後は、もう少しフレームワークまでコードを追ってみようと思います。